# Quickbooks desktop web connector, invoice CLASS is empty

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

I've been using QuickBooks Enterprise, Web connector ver: 2.1.0.30 and the framework found here: https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php for adding invoices and jobs. It is working fine but I can't get the CLASS of the invoice to be shown in quickbooks. I pass it correctly in my xml (I get no error and the invoice gets added), as described in accepted answer here: [quickbooks desktop web connector qbxml: add invoice with CLASS field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28125103/quickbooks-desktop-web-connector-qbxml-add-invoice-with-class-field) but it doesn't show in quickbooks. Here is the part of my xml:

`...<InvoiceLineAdd>
    <ItemRef>
        <FullName>item name</FullName>
    </ItemRef>
    <Desc>item description</Desc>
    <Quantity>2</Quantity>
    <Rate>123</Rate>
    <ClassRef>
        <FullName>class name</FullName>
    </ClassRef>
</InvoiceLineAdd>...`

When I edit the invoice in quickbooks it has no CLASS selected and CLASS field is empty, I can't post screen-shot, the CLASS field appears as a dropdown right next to CUSTOMER JOB field when editing the invoice.

So is there anything else I should do for the class to show up?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding `Class` to the invoice *line*. If you want it at the *invoice* level, you need to use the `ClassRef` in the invoice and not on the line.